# ListView disappears when DatePicker is added

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, datepicker

I am currently writing an Android Project but I am having problems in my xml file. Without the datepicker, the listview is working well. However, when I add a datepicker(without editing the java file), the listview disppears. The following is my android xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Date"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

  <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirm" /> 

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there something wrong in my xml file?

UPDATE:
I found out that the listview appears on samsung galaxy Y duos even with the datepicker but still does not appear on a samsung galaxy note

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I used a DatePicker and a ListView with a custom adapter in the same layout, and with my activity extending ListActivity and calling getListView(). The list appeared on older versions of Android, but not on newer versions. I experienced that my adapter's getView() method wasn't called.

I got it to work on newer versions by changing android:id="@android:id/list" to a custom id, and calling findViewById with this id, but then the older versions got a "RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'". To make it work on both old and new versions I used the custom id and the findViewById method, but extending from Activity instead of ListActivity. Perhaps there are ways of dealing with this without avoiding the ListActivity, but this worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the widgets before the ListView end up taking up all the vertical space and your listview just has no room to appear. Try Setting the height of the TextView,Button and  DatePicker to something like 10dp and see if you can see the list then. If you can , its a space issue and you should consider using a `ScrollView` instead of a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Tried ScrollView but to no avail. I also tried setting the height of the DatePicker to 10dp but the ListView still does not show up. However, when I remove the Datepicker and even increase the size of the TextVIew and Button, the ListView appears.

Comment: Found out that my code posted above works on Samsung Galaxy Y but not on Samsung Galaxy Note. What does this mean?

Comment: Your parent `LinearLayout` doesnt seem to have an end tag. Was that just a mistake copying .. or? Also, you dont really need to wrap the `ListView` in a `LinearLayout`. Just have it as a child of the parent `LinearLayout` and have it's height set to "wrap_content".

Comment: Sorry. That was a mistake in copying. That is not actually needed for this version but I am planning to add a button later. Still, even without the wrapping the ListView in a LinearLayout, the ListView still does not appear.

Comment: Okay. Ive tried running your layout in a project and declaring the namespace in the child elements causes lint to throw an error. Try removing the "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" from all the elements except the parent `LinearLayout`. Other than that your layout works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove this Line

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

except from the top layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign weight to your layouts and see.
add     android:layout_weight="1" to both of your linear layouts (don't add this to your main linear layout)